# /etc/fstab syntax incompatible between auto-mount and manual mount of CIFS

Tags: centos, fstab, cifs

When I use this `fstab` syntax:

```
# grep raven /etc/fstab
\\raven.example.com\raven      /raven          cifs    vers=2.0,credentials=/root/creds_smb_raven,\
    uid=5000,gid=6000,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775       0       0
```

and reboot, the auto-mount fails, even though a manual re-try succeeds.  I see:

```
# mount -t cifs
# grep -w mount.cifs /var/log/messages
Jan 27 11:59:16 myhost mount: mount.cifs: bad UNC (\raven.example.com\raven)
# mount /raven
# mount -t cifs
\\raven.example.com\raven on /raven type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.0,cache=strict,username=surfgeo,domain=raven,uid=5000,forceuid,gid=6000,forcegid,addr=10.27.4.22,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

But when I double up the backslashes:

```
\\\\raven.example.com\\raven   /raven          cifs    vers=2.0,credentials=/root/creds_smb_raven,uid=5000,gid=6000,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775       0       0
```

and reboot, the auto-mount succeeds but manual mounting is now broken.  I get:

```
# mount -t cifs
\\raven.example.com\raven on /raven type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.0,cache=strict,username=surfgeo,domain=raven,uid=5000,forceuid,gid=6000,forcegid,addr=10.27.4.22,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
# umount /raven
# mount /raven
mount.cifs: bad UNC (\\\\raven.example.com\\raven)
```

Is there one specific `fstab` syntax that will work both for auto-mount at boot
and manual unmount/remount after boot?

Comment: what if you use forward slashes!?

Comment: @JaromandaX That works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, use forward slashes instead of backslashes:

```
//raven.example.com/raven      /raven          cifs    vers=2.0,credentials=/root/creds_smb_raven,\
    uid=5000,gid=6000,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775       0       0
```